# How to pass the data provided by the user to the next activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

```
    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReferenceFromUrl("https://messageplus-cd647.firebaseio.com/");
    addData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            MyUser user;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            EditText userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_phone_number);
            user = new MyUser(input_name.getText().toString(), input_email.getText().toString(), input_status.getText().toString(), input_quote.getText().toString());
            ref.child("Users").child(String.valueOf(userNumber)).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        //USER SAVED
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is the code in the second activity... A child is created called Users. and another child of phone number should be created. The number should be of the user provided in the first activity. but instead of the number its showing null.. the rest of the data is getting added properly. i have trouble getting the phone number provided by the user in the prev class. please help! thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to pass data from one activity to another? or you cant get the number from the database?

Comment: You can stuff key value pairs for primitive types into the intent directly or make your class parcelable and pass the parcelable inside the intent

Comment: i want to pass the data from the first activity to the second.

Comment: to access the second activity the user will have to provide his phone number and get authenticated. the code works fine. but i'm unable to get that provided phone number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im gonna assume first activity is for `sign up` and second is for `login`, then to get the phone number from sign up to login do this:

```
 //in SignupActivity

String number=edittext.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.putExtra("your_number",number);
startActivity(i)
finish();
```

`number` string contains the phone number which is passed to the other activity using `putExtra`

---

```
//under onCreate() in LoginActivity

 Intent i = getIntent();
 String s = i.getStringExtra("your_number");
```

`s` string contains the phone number that is passed to `LoginActivity`

Then you can use this phone number to authenticate the user.

Also there is no need in using `getReferencefromUrl`, can just do this:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AllUser").push();
 ref.child("phonenumber").setValue(s);
```

Either use `push()` (as above) or do this:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AllUser").child(user.getUid());
```

Comment: Omg.. dude ur like God for me right now. I've been breaking my head since 2days... Tysfm

Comment: Add it under phone number `ref.child("phonenumber").child("data").setValue(data)`... Like this for all data

Comment: what is not working?? do this: `ref.child("phonenumber").child("name").setValue(peter);` `ref.child("phonenumber").child("familyname").setValue(haddad);`.. no other solution to do it

Comment: Tysm dude... n sorry for all the trouble u went through

Comment: it's fine no problem!! happy coding!